# Verification Phone Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

I want to create a different/new Play Store account in my new device, but when the Play Store asks me for my phone number, it says that it was used too many times.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) There is no Play Store account but Google account 2) Google account can be created using browser from any machine, so you can use it 3) That issue about phone number comes up when you've your phone number registered to too many Google accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the response; just one more question, that means that it is impossible to register more accounts with my phone number? there is not a way?

Comment: I don't think so. Why not use one of those other accounts in Play Store?

Comment: What do you need so many accounts for? Usually one suffices, in some cases you might need a second one (testing, family member). If it's for testing only, who forces you to register a phone number with it? I never did that, and my 2 accounts still work fine.